# Assign Current GridView Data Table to Session?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView consisting of editable text boxes.  When the user enters a value, the `OnTextChanged` function calls my `UpdateColumns()` method, which performs various calculations and alters the whole GridView.  I have limited user input to only numbers so that the operation errors out when the user enters alpha characters in any cell.  Upon this error, I would like to revert to the Data Table that existed immediately prior to the user entering the alpha character.

Is there a way to capture the current GridView's data source and store in a DataTable?

I have tried the following (after the data table has been bound):

```
Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(gvBuildingBlocks.DataSource, DataTable)
Session("buildingBlocks") = dt

'If textboxes are all numeric, perform calculations here 

'Else display error here and bind table below
gvBuildingBlocks.DataSource = CType(Session("buildingBlocks"), DataTable)
gvBuildingBlocks.DataBind()
```

The above results in an empty gridview, as the value of `gvBuildingBlocks.DataSource` is empty.  Is there anything else I can do to get the values?

I imagine I could loop through all the rows and save them somehow as follows:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow in gvBuildingBlocks.Rows
    'Save cell value here
Next
```

But I don't know what code to use to save the values?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not set the session variable when you bind the gridview at the first time?

Comment: I am actually already doing that.  But what if the user makes several correct changes and then accidentally enters an 'a' in a textbox?  It will revert back to the original databound gridview, which will result in a loss of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you are doing calculations on rows and you want to rollback to original values if the user input is invalid. You could accomplish this at the row level by calling `DataRow.BeginEdit()` before the edit, and `DataRow.CancelEdit()` if the input is invalid. See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.beginedit.aspx)

Don't forget to call `DataRow.EndEdit()` if the edit is valid to commit changes.